# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (unless I'm using a proxy)

Tags: wordpress, timeout

I run my own online business as well as managing over a dozen self hosted sites for other people using the wordpress.org. platform. They're all hosted by a small company in the UK and if I do experience any problems the company are usually quick to sort them out. However...

Right now, using Chrome or Safari (on an iMac and on a PC) I'm getting the message ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when attempting to login to the wp-admin; or even if I just want to view the sites. It's not the first time this has happened, and I've done all the usual things - cleared the browser cache, double checked the wi-fi connection, used a 'is it down or is it just me' site etc. etc. Btw, the sites are accessible from elsewhere (but this doesn't help me, I live and work out in the sticks.) I've done pings and traceroutes and copied my hosting provider into these (no reply, yet.)

I can access the sites using a proxy (e.g. anonymouse) but can't edit them in this way of course. Anyway, this wouldn't be a great solution, I want to be able to use Chrome or Safari. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Latest. Now can't access the admin any of those sites I manage again, well I can for a few minutes, before the err_connection_timed_out message appears. My domain/hosting provider tells me all's fine at their end and the problem lies with BT. Trying to discuss this with someone at BT is useless. Really at a loss to know what to do, I've tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be DNS related. Are you able to ping the websites? Can you navigate to them by IP address?

Comment: Thanks @Jonas, I feel it's a DNS-related problem too, although this is a steep learning curve for me! If I navigate to any of the sites I manage, such as my own, using the site's IP, I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. I've run a ping and traceroute from the terminal on my Mac and get a heap of request timeouts.

Comment: Sounds like your ISP may be having some DNS issues if this happens intermittently. Have you tried an ipconfig /flushdns and then trying again? Do you have a static setup on your PC with your network? DHCP?

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the site via proxy, like Jonas Lear said, it could be DNS related but it can also be a route issue.

1. Validate your DNS resolvers and that you can at least return a name resolution using NSLOOKUP or DIG.  If you can at least get there, you got a network path problem.
2. Validate a ping to verify layer 2/3.  If that doesn't happen, validate the proxy server's gateway and routes versus yours.  Validate you get return traffic from the site using wireshark.  If you only see outbound traffic, you have an asynchronous route and that's not going to help.  Proxy servers would bypass this symptom.
3. You're blocked by an IPS and the Proxy allows an alternate way out.  If you're not the admin and don't know your egress path, find out.

My money is on 2 if DNS works.

Comment: Thanks Chaseabbott I shall take some time to read and work through your suggestions carefully! (forgive me, I'm a beginner is all.)

Comment: Everyone's a beginner at one point.  ;-)  Also remember to check your host file if the only sites that are not working are sites you manage.  I've forgotten to remove entries in my host file I manually made for testing.

Comment: All is working this morning, but I'm perplexed. Yesterday I connected my main computer to ethernet and logged in to all of my sites successfully, no time outs. I was then able to log into the same sites using wi-fi on other computers in my premises. That the connection worked on ethernet could just be a coincidence. Still no word from the ISP (indicating they're not receiving my mails since they're normally so speedy.) Thanks anyway @JonasLear and Chaseabbott. The new year will be a good time for me to think about dedicated server rental. Meanwhile the steep learning curve continues.